# Set Inverval breaks when using UseEffect in React

Tags: arrays, reactjs, react-hooks, setinterval, use-effect

I have an array of text I am transition through, when I reach the end it loops back to 0 and plays again. All is working fine after the first pass, then it gets out of synch and speeds up. Any thoughts on how to solve this?

Codesanbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/text-show-forked-zqkvz

JS:

```
const Loader = (props) => {
  const { messages } = props;
  const [messageIndex, setMessageIndex] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    setInterval(() => {
      if (messageIndex === messages.length - 1) {
        setMessageIndex(0);
      } else {
        setMessageIndex(messageIndex + 1);
      }
    }, 2000);
  }, [messages, messageIndex]);

  return <div>{messages[messageIndex]}</div>;
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Loader messages={messages} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your particular case, it would be enough to clear interval:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      if (messageIndex === messages.length - 1) {
        setMessageIndex(0);
      } else {
        setMessageIndex(messageIndex + 1);
      }
    }, 2000);

    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, [messages, messageIndex]);
```

However, I would encourage you to read an [article](https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks/) by Dan Abramov regarding working `setInterval` and react hooks.

TL;DR

you can use a custom hook:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

function useInterval(callback, delay) {
  const savedCallback = useRef();

  // Remember the latest callback.
  useEffect(() => {
    savedCallback.current = callback;
  }, [callback]);

  // Set up the interval.
  useEffect(() => {
    function tick() {
      savedCallback.current();
    }
    if (delay !== null) {
      let id = setInterval(tick, delay);
      return () => clearInterval(id);
    }
  }, [delay]);
}
```

So instead of your `useEffect` it would be something like:

```
    useInterval(() => {
      if (messageIndex === messages.length - 1) {
        setMessageIndex(0);
      } else {
        setMessageIndex(messageIndex + 1);
      }
    }, 2000)
```

Comment: @user992731 welcome. please consider looking at the answer update regarding custom hook